# Nativescript splash file background color

Tags: nativescript

Instead of a bitmap - can I set the background color for the splash screen

`<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="fill">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>`

Comment: Hi dashman you could use `nativescript-splashscreen` plugin to style the splashscreen as you wish. In the plugins repo you could review the attached demo - https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-splashscreen/tree/master/demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it just as you would in the native environment.

***app/App_Resources/Android/drawable-nodpi/splash_screen.xml***

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:gravity="fill">
    <item android:drawable="@color/my_color"/>
</layer-list>
```

and do not forget to 'register' your color

***app/App_Resources/Android/values/colors.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="my_color">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```